# Mod Rewrite Wildcard Folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Just wondering if its possible to use a wildcard domain in my htaccess file with a folder.

For example redirecting (^.*).test.com/myfolder/ to folder/test.php?id=$1

This is what I have so far but no idea how to add a folder after the URL:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.test\.com
RewriteRule ^ folder/test.php?id=%1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.test\.com
RewriteRule ^$ folder/test.php?id=%1
```

We rewrite for example `http://www.test.com/` to `http://www.test.com/folder/test.php?id=www`

Is this what you want ?

Comment: No sorry, I want to redirect (^.*).test.com/myfolder/ to folder/test.php?id=$1

I am having trouble implementing the /myfolder/ part

Comment: @jamdav16: What is an example of rewritten URI?